# How do you mark a duplicate that isn't "quite" a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Specifically, these two recent questions:

[Chubbyness from the face and body](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/chubbyness-from-the-face-and-body)

[Slimming legs with exercise and diet](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18098/slimming-legs-with-exercise-and-diet)

Both are asking how to spot reduce a body area, which is essentially a duplicate of "How to remove belly fat fast". The questions are not duplicates, but the answers will be.

How is this generally handled?

Answer (score 2):

Though the two questions have the same or similar answer, I wouldn't consider the two questions to be the "same" question. Not all questions will boil down to the ["Best exercise to lose belly fat fast"](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/best-exercise-to-lose-belly-fat-fast) question.

If it's a duplicate of the exact question, then mark it as closed. Otherwise, leave it open and answer it accordingly and even reference the other questions as needed.

It may be worth it in the long run to have one canonical question about spot reduction that everyone can refer to or use to close others as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

From Matt's answer:

> have one canonical question about spot reduction that everyone can refer to or use to close others as a duplicate.

This is the way to go. Write a knock-it-out-of-the-park destruction of spot reduction. Then link to it every chance you get, and tell everybody else to do so too. I do a little bit of this with spot reduction, but it takes a while to find my go-to link.

Comment: I started favorit'ing some of the more common duplicates I've run across.